# How to control arrangement of view formatted list items?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, view-formatting

I have a sharepoint list that uses view formatting. The height of each item depends on the content within it, they are arranged with 4 in each row when the browser is maximised. The columns display really weirdly as a result. Is there any way to sort them by height or control how the items are laid out?

Basically I want a way to better fill all the whitespace in the image below as right now it looks bad, especially as the boxes get longer.

[image: Bad list layout]

```
{
"schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
"hideSelection": true,
"hideListHeader": true,
"rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "float": "left",
        "display": "flex",
        "flex-wrap": "nowrap",
        "flex-direction": "column",
        "align-items": "left",
        "justify-content": "flex-start",
        "width": "320px",
        "height": "auto",
        "border-radius": "2px",
        "margin-right": "15px",
        "margin-bottom": "15px",
        "box-shadow": "2px 2px 8px darkgrey",
        "border-style": "solid",
        "border-width": "4px",
        "background-color": "#ffffff",
        "color": "black"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "[$Title]",
            "style": {
                "font-size": "2rem",
                "text-align": "center",
                "vertical-align": "middle",
                "width": "80%",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "padding": "1rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "=[$Multi]",
            "style": {
                "font-size": "1.4rem",
                "text-align": "center",
                "vertical-align": "middle",
                "width": "100%",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "padding": "0.8rem 2rem 0.5rem 2rem"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Could you include some screenshots?

Comment: I'll try mock up an example tomorrow but can't show mine due to confidentiality I'm afraid.

Comment: @RuneSperre done :)

Comment: I see, you probably want to have something like masonry layout? I doubt this is possible using view formatting alone as a new row will begin once the width has been reached (and you would need a top container to modify). You could even the spacing with min/max height but I'm guessing that's not what you want to achieve...

Comment: @RuneSperre yeah that's what I'm aiming for but can't edit the container all the items are in. I want the cards to be dynamically sized so basically need to edit that top container

Comment: I think an extension is your only option then I am afraid

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You would need to add more css to further manipulate the list view since you cannot control the outer (top) container from the list formatter. an SPFx extension could help you solve that bit (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions)

Comment: Have there been any new developments in list formatting that would make this possible in an easier way now?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am building something similar and have run into the same issue. **edit:** Sorry this is posted as an answer. I can't post comments yet. =/

Comment: @TrentonM no I didn't! If you find a solution please let me know...